# How to get location through message in android

Tags: android, gps

Basically I want to develop an app whose ultimate goal is to mark attendance of the employees on basis of location where they are sitting.First of all I would enter the locations of each user into table and then will compare the location fetched by sending messages to each employees mobile.If both the locations match then attendance will be marked.
So my question is that , is it possible to get location of user by sending message? or there will be another option to get location of user?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done if you install an app to the user's phone which reads your message with some particular text (can be password) and then use SMSService to reply with the location of the user. I can give you a code sample if you want.

you will have to create a BroadcastReceiver

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import com.geoadrs.utility.ConnectionDetector;
    import com.geoadrs.utility.JSONParser;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        Intent in;
        String contact;


        Context c;


        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            c = context;
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            data = c.getSharedPreferences("appdata", 0);
            String str = "SMS From: ";
            if (bundle != null) {
                // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        contact = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();// getting
                                                                    // sender's
                                                                    // address
                        // str+= contact;
                        // str+=" : ";
                    }

                    str = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

                }

                if (str.contains("your_password")) {
                    /*
                    use you location methoid to get location
                    */
                    //after getting location
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message+"with the location you want to send"+location, null, null);

                }
                // ---display the new SMS message---
                // Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). You can deliver asynchronously push notifications to Android devices. The clients can send you their locations after receiving a "push"-notification. Mr Murphy has a nice [example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push).